# For complex $z$, find all solutions to: $(z - 6 + i)^3 = -27$

Tags: complex-numbers

> For complex $z$, find all solutions to: $(z - 6 + i)^3 = -27$

I reasoned that for this to be true, $z - 6 + i$ must be $= -3$

$\therefore z - 3 + i = 0$

$z = 3 - i$

However, there are two more solutions provided for this problem and I am not sure how to get to them. What is the standard method for solving something like this to ensure that all answers are produced?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation $u^3=-27$ has three solutions $u$ in $\mathbb C$. Can you describe them? Hint: [polar representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form) of complex numbers and [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Once this is done, you will see that the equation $(z-6+\mathrm i)^3=-27$ has three solutions as well, and you will be able to write them down (one of them is $3-\mathrm i$, of course).

Answer (score 4):

$(z - 6 + i)^3 = -27$ is of the form $u^3=(-3)^3$, which can be factored over $\mathbb{C}$ as:

$$u^3-(-3)^3=(u-(-3))(u^2+u(-3)+(-3)^2)=(u+3)(u^2-3u+9) $$

One root is $u=-3$.

The other two roots, one can get after solving quadratic equation $u^2-3u+9=0$.

Answer (score 2):

First Try to find all the cube roots of $-27$.(Or whatever it is that is relevant to your problem)

To do this you write down Complex numbers in their Polar form. **Or in the form**
$$z=r(\cos\theta+\text{i}\sin\theta)$$
Where $\theta$ is the *argument* of $z$ and $r$ its *modulus* or *norm* (or its length (on the Argand Diagram) in simple terms). Finding out the cube roots of $-27$ is not a very difficult thing to do. But for this you require the knowledge of **de Moivre's Theorem**. It deals with computing powers of complex numbers. It says (for now, just trust the equation and move along:) I will not give you a proof here)
$$r(\cos\theta+\text{i}\sin\theta)^n=r^n(\cos n\theta+\text{i}\sin n\theta)\tag{1}$$
How do you use this to find the cube roots? Well, Just assume that for some $u\in  \mathbb C$ with argument $\alpha$ and modulus $q$,
$$[q(\cos\alpha+\text{i}\sin\alpha)]^3=-27$$
Or, from the result of de Moivre's Theorem,
$$q^3(\cos 3\alpha+\text{i}\sin 3\alpha)=-27(\cos 0+\text i \sin0)\tag{2}$$
Equation $(2)$ suggests that
$q^3=-27 ~~~~~\implies~ q=\sqrt[3]{-27}=-3 $, and 
$3\alpha=0~~~~~~~~~\implies3\alpha=0, 2\pi ~\text{or}~ 4\pi\implies~\alpha =0 ,~ \frac23\pi~~\text{or} ~~\frac43\pi~$

You now have three sets of possible values for $\alpha$ which is, if you remember, the argument of you cube roots of $-27$ and as given in your answer, has three values that it can take.
[Note that for all three $\alpha$s, the value for the modulus of the roots $($or $q)$ is always the same ($-3$). This is where your problem came about. (You didd not consider other possible roots)]

So now, we have found all values that a complex number, say $u$ can take where
$$u^3=-27$$
And your question asks you to find the solution to the equation
$$(z - 6 + \text i)^3 = -27$$

Notice the similarity? They are in similar forms right? So it would be fair to say that

$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~u=(z - 6 + \text i)$$
$$\implies z=u+6-\text i \tag{3}$$
From this you easily get 3 values for $z$ (using the three solutions for $u$ that we got earlier on)

---

**Note:** During the last step, you need to change solutions for $u$ from their Polar form to the usual $a+b\text i$ format. The reason should be apparent from $(3)$

---

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The other approach to this problem could be to rewrite equation into form :

$z^3-(18-3i)z^2+(105-36i)z-(171-107i)=0$

and then to use [general formula for the roots of the cubic equation .](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots)

Comment: Since one solution $z_0$ is already known I'd rather divide that expression by $z-z_0$ and end up with a quadratic equation than use that formula.

Comment: @Thomas Good point....